# Change an image in Gimp with a gradient like a shiny button or sticker tab

Tags: gimp

I have this image with a gradient as below:

[image: blue tab with gradient]

I need to change it to the color #D21108 (type of RED). Of course, I do not want to paint it to this color, but to change the color to #D21108 and its shades (like I do in Photoshop via Brush > Colour Replacement). I have all info about this color, values of RGB, CMYK, Lab and HSV if you need them.

Now, I guess I can easily change it via GIMP's menu "Colors". I tried options Color Balance, Hue-Saturation, Colorize, but I did not find a way to enter the starting color I need. I was closest to my aim via Hue-Saturation, but I could not get this red value, no matter what I tried.

As I am not a graphics expert, please tell me how to accomplish this task.

PS. What's the meaning of Lab and HSV in the color scheme? I know the meaning of RGB and CMYK.

Comment: Its the actual image, the lines are there already. Its only due to the light colour that you cant see it directly

Comment: HSV stands for hue, saturation, value. I don't know what Lab means, though.

Comment: Value? What's the meaning of this? I usually find this combination hue, saturation and lightness. Is value = lightness? Regarding Lab, in the color scheme its literary what I wrote: capital 'L' and small letters 'a' and 'b'

Comment: You image IS multiple colors. You may have started with one, but some application changed portions of it. You would need to change it to that one color, and then have the same application or process applied the same changes to that new colored image.

Comment: Hm, this is rather slow process. As I have the color scheme I was looking a way to find it somewhere and apply it.

Comment: Lab is an alternative color space description where L indicates lightness, a is the red-green axis and b is the blue-yellow axis. A more complete description is found here http://www.hunterlab.com/appnotes/an08_96a.pdf

Comment: If photoshop you set your color first. The using the "Hue-Saturation -> Colorize" command will default to your active color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brush > Colour Replacement

[image: Colour Replacement Tool]

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zm7BCw_E9wU

EDIT:
For GIMP -

Look at image title - if not RGB save it as .png or .gif
To change color wherever it is in entire image:
Select 'Color Tool' – (rectangular 3-color bar on top row)
Click on color to be changed
Select Edit and choose: Clear to eliminate color
Edit and fill with a) foreground color or b) background color

Comment: What about GIMP? Any ideas?

Comment: I used GIMP tool "Select by color". Clicked on one color and got radial selection. I was able to change it but this is rather precise task because the gradient image consists of more than 3 colors (like I thought on the first place). Was this the tool you were talking about?

Comment: PHOTOSHOP: When I use the Color replacement tool, the process is really simple, but I end up with and image that has horizontal stripes like the tool was not able to color the migration from one color to another. Could you tell me am I doing something wrong?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zm7BCw_E9wU - Here is me doing it (I suggest switching to 480p to view properly)

Comment: Hm, I did the same. Do you think it matters if I used a smaller brush size?

Comment: Are you able to send across the image with the issue you are having?

Comment: I will edit the question

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop use Image->Adjustments-> Hue/Saturation. For your image this would be the easiest way to change the color.

Comment: This is image taken from the Internet. I have it in the form of JPG or PNG. I do not have the Photoshop file.

Comment: Not to mention that I would have to be guru to get the color I need :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Colors>Hue-Saturation. Also Colorify works for some adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

i'll just post the colored version for you:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ian, but I'd like to do it myself. Did you finish it in Photoshop or in GIMP?

Comment: i did it in photoshop. i get the foreground first to your red (#d21108). Then **Image** -> **Adjustments** -> **Hue/Saturation** and check **Colorize**. i tried googling for the gimp equivalent of those tools ("*Colorize*", "*Hue/Saturation*"), but couldn't find it (as my comment on the question said). But i thought i'd still be helpful and just do it - since you said you needed it.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I know how to do it in Photoshop (via Color Replacement tool) in easy way. It's just that GIMP is another tool I'd like to learn how to accomplish this as well.