# Gimp: Change all shades of pink to an equivalent shade of green in JPG?

Tags: images, gimp, image-editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gimp: change one colour to another?](https://superuser.com/questions/153248/gimp-change-one-colour-to-another)

I have a JPG image that is made up of different shades of blue and pink. I would like to change all the pink in the image to the equivalent shade of green.

I know about GIMP's "[Select by Color](https://superuser.com/questions/304031/change-an-image-in-gimp-with-a-gradient-like-a-shiny-button-or-sticker-tab)" tool, but my problem is that there isn't just one shade of pink in the image, there are about 10, from dark pink to very light.

So I can manually select all the dark pink and change it to dark green, the slightly lighter pink and change it to slightly lighter green, etc.

But this is laborious and doesn't give a very good result.

Is there any way that I can map all the shades of pink to an equivalent shade of green?

Comment: That answer suggests using Colorize - after much Googling I still can't figure out how to use Colorize to do what I need, so any advice would still be appreciated.

Comment: Nope, definitely can't figure it out - Colorize seems to be a way to add an overall colour filter to an image, not to map one colour to another.

Comment: Just because the accepted answer isn't the one you want, the question is still the same.  If you want better/newer answers to an existing question, please consider [setting a bounty](http://superuser.com/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: True enough :) but the bounties for better/newer answers is still the way to go.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to add a bounty, unfortunately. But feel free to close this question if you want.

Comment: OK, the answer beginning "I suggest rotating Hue in Colors → Hue-Saturation" in the duplicate question is the actual answer.